# Alfresco - PHP Integration

Tags: php, xampp, alfresco

i am trying to integrate `Alfresco PHP API` . and still i am having this error.

> Warning: Declaration of AlfrescoWebService::__soapCall($function_name,
>   $arguments = Array, $options = Array, $input_headers = Array,
>   $output_headers = Array) should be compatible with
>   SoapClient::__soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options = NULL,
>   $input_headers = NULL, &$output_headers = NULL) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php on
>   line 97
>
> Warning: Declaration of AlfrescoWebService::__doRequest($request,
>   $location, $action, $version) should be compatible with
>   SoapClient::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version,
>   $one_way = NULL) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php on
>   line 97
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService?wsdl' :
>   failed to load external entity
>   "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/AuthenticationService?wsdl" in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php:31
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php(31):
>   SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfresco\Service\WebService\WebServiceFactory.php(26):
>   AlfrescoWebService->__construct('http://localhos...', Array) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfresco\Service\Repository.php(56):
>   WebServiceFactory::getAuthenticationService('http://localhos...') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(16): Repository->authenticate('admin',
>   'abc123') #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Alfresco\Service\WebService\AlfrescoWebService.php on
>   line 31

can anyone help me how to integrate PHP API?

Comment: isn't  "Alfresco" that pasta with flat noodles and white sauce on it?

Comment: Why are you using the ancient and unsupported WebServices stuff? What happens if you swap to the newer CMIS support?

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco-PHP Integration was a wrapper around the Alfresco-Web-Services-API (SOAP) which is no longer available. Please use [Alfresco REST API](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/)  or [Alfresco CMIS API](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/pra/1/concepts/cmis-basics.html) instead.